# The username supplied is invalid

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, dotnetopenauth

I have a certain problem in MVC membership that is killing me. I am using OAuth with Facebook for my website and it is workin fine unless; if the username (in this situation Name and Surname) contains "i", i am getting that error at the page mysite/Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The username supplied is invalid.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException: The username supplied is invalid.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Just to be more clear if username is "Meta Brown" it is perfectly fine bu if the user name is "Hail Brown" or semething i am getting the error above.

And at the  mysite/Account/Register page if i choose username like "hail", i am getting this exclamtaion:

```
The authentication provider returned an error. Please verify your entry and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your system administrator.
```

Bottom line when i am registering via Facebook if username contains character "i" my table of webpages_OAuthMembership keeping empty and when i am registering via MVC membership system my table of webpages_Membership keeping empty.

I've also added a control for non-Latin characters:

```
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Please use Latin characters only.")]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't understand `i` is a latin character.

Comment: this why i am asking... isn't it weired? :/

Comment: At this point I would start your configuration process from scrach.  Because the use of `i` in a word causing this error makes zero no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change the username field in the userprofile table into the latin. it should solve the problem.

it should be look like this:

Latin1_General_CI_AS